# Textbox control is automatically increase width depending on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Textbox control is automatically increase width depending on fill text from database in asp.net

Comment: Have you given width to the textbox??

Comment: yes, I given width to the textbox

Comment: Can you send your code??

Comment: This is a problem that you have or a result that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function Increse(obj){
      if (!obj.s) obj.s=obj.size;
      obj.size=Math.max(obj.s,obj.value.length);
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form>
       <input  type="text" size="5" style="font-family:Courier;" onkeyup="Increse(this);">
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: The values are coming from database. Here i don't know why we need onkeyup function

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtMgrEmail" runat="server" CssClass="txtboxcss" Width="212px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: I din't see that values coming from db. You can do one thing, Set AutoSize : false and then expend the text box to max text value.

Comment: How to set Autosize :false  ?

Comment: txtMgrEmail.Text = dt.Rows[0]["branchemailid"].ToString();

<asp:TextBox ID="txtMgrEmail" runat="server" CssClass="txtboxcss" Width="212px"  ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: No that will not work in your case. You have to create a logic for this. Count the length of the text and then set the width of the textbox accordingly using javascript.

Comment: use same javascript code, replace onkeyup to onfocus and change accordingly.